# Can't find date in calendar (Python+Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How I can find date in Calendar.

I've used xpath,css_selector and always I see **Message: element not visible**

Help me pls if you can

I tried :

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='flatpickr-day nextMonthDay'][@aria-label='November 10, 2018']").click()
```

Code of calendar:

http://prntscr.com/l4bmw8

Sorry for my hardly English

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text formatted html

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? I'm guessing if it's a calendar that it might be initially hidden and require a click to open the calendar and that's why you are getting the error that the element is not visible. Is the calendar initially open?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

You may explicitly wait for a certain action to be occurred. The extreme case of this is `time.sleep()`. However, if must wait for a given time in `time.sleep()` method, `EC` lets you to wait only as long as you required.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Presence waits for the element to be in the DOM, not to be visible. You can wait for visible though but I'm not sure that's what the issue is here.